# stacking two wx.Grid resizing only the second

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to create two grids stacked vertically in the same frame. 
since it is not possible to disable the scroll bars grids I am trying this turn around
the first grid must occupy the top part of the frame while the second one the lower part. when the frame is resized the top grid must stay all the time visible with no scroll bars while the lower grid can show scroll bars.
here is an example code. the only issue is that I am not able to make the first grid occupy only its size in the frame, it is occupying the half of the frame no matter what.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as glib
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as SP

# The main panel:        
class grids(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)
        # scrolled panels
        resizableScrolledPanel = SP.ScrolledPanel(self)
        fixedScrolledPanel = SP.ScrolledPanel(self)
        # main sizer for everything:
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # create grids
        fixGrid = glib.Grid(fixedScrolledPanel)
        resizableGrid = glib.Grid(resizableScrolledPanel)
        # customize grids
        fixGrid.CreateGrid(3,10)
        resizableGrid.CreateGrid(20,10)
        fixGrid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour( [176, 196, 222] )#light steel blue
        fixGrid.SetGridLineColour([0,0,0])
        [fixGrid.SetRowLabelValue(idx, ["row 1","row 2","row 3"][idx]) for idx in range(3)]
        resizableGrid.SetColLabelSize(0)
        fixGrid.SetRowLabelSize( wx.grid.GRID_AUTOSIZE )
        resizableGrid.SetRowLabelSize( fixGrid.GetRowLabelSize() )
        # Create the grids sizers
        propSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        dataSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        propSizer.Add(fixGrid,1,wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,5)
        dataSizer.Add(resizableGrid,1,wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND,5)
        fixedScrolledPanel.SetSizer(propSizer)
        resizableScrolledPanel.SetSizer(dataSizer)
        fixedScrolledPanel.Layout()
        resizableScrolledPanel.Layout()
        resizableScrolledPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=True, scroll_y=True)
        fixedScrolledPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scroll_y=False)
        # add to main sizer
        mainSizer.Add(fixedScrolledPanel,1,wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,5)
        mainSizer.Add(resizableScrolledPanel,1,wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND,5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Fit()

        print fixedScrolledPanel.GetSize() # returns (0,0)

# The main frame:
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,title=title, size=(850,500))
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer.Add(grids(self),1,wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.SetAutoLayout(1)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame(None, "Scroll Test")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Normally I should set the mainSizer proportion to 0 for the fixedScrolledPanel like this

```
mainSizer.Add(fixedScrolledPanel,0,wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,5)
```

but since fixedScrolledPanel is (0,0) the first grid disapears ...

Answer (score 1):

The missing detail was the `SetSizeHints` call; the sizers needed to know what to scale to. You also want the panels in `mainSizer` to have `proportion = 0`.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as glib
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as SP

# The main panel:        
class grids(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)
        # scrolled panels
        resizableScrolledPanel = SP.ScrolledPanel(self)
        fixedScrolledPanel = SP.ScrolledPanel(self)
        # main sizer for everything:
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # create grids
        fixGrid = glib.Grid(fixedScrolledPanel)
        resizableGrid = glib.Grid(resizableScrolledPanel)
        # customize grids
        fixGrid.CreateGrid(3,10)
        resizableGrid.CreateGrid(20,10)
        fixGrid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour( [176, 196, 222] )#light steel blue
        fixGrid.SetGridLineColour([0,0,0])
        [fixGrid.SetRowLabelValue(idx, ["row 1","row 2","row 3"][idx]) for idx in range(3)]
        resizableGrid.SetColLabelSize(0)
        fixGrid.SetRowLabelSize( wx.grid.GRID_AUTOSIZE )
        resizableGrid.SetRowLabelSize( fixGrid.GetRowLabelSize() )
        # Create the grids sizers
        fixedSizer  = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        resizeSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        resizableScrolledPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=True, scroll_y=True)
        fixedScrolledPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scroll_y=False)

        fixedSizer.Add\
        (
            fixGrid,
            proportion = 1,
            flag       = wx.EXPAND,
            border     = 0
        )
        fixedScrolledPanel.SetSizer(fixedSizer)
        fixedSizer.SetSizeHints(fixedScrolledPanel)
        mainSizer.Add\
        (
            fixedScrolledPanel,
            proportion = 0,
            flag       = wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP,
            border     = 5
        )
        resizeSizer.Add\
        (
            resizableGrid,
            proportion = 1,
            flag       = wx.EXPAND,
            border     = 0
        )
        resizableScrolledPanel.SetSizer(resizeSizer)
        resizeSizer.SetSizeHints(resizableScrolledPanel)
        mainSizer.Add\
        (
            resizableScrolledPanel,
            proportion = 0,
            flag       = wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM,
            border     = 5
        )
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)

# The main frame:
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,title=title, size=(850,500))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(grids(self),1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame(None, "Scroll Test")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

I reformatted your code for readability.

Comment: thank you, we are half way there. what you suggested fixed the size of the grids but upon resizing the frame the resizableScrolledPanel doesn't show the scroll bars !

Comment: I think this time i got it right. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

@ dilbert
few modification were needed to fix the scroll bars

```
import wx
import wx.grid as glib
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as SP

# The main panel:        
class grids(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)
        # scrolled panels
        resizableScrolledPanel = SP.ScrolledPanel(self)
        fixedScrolledPanel = SP.ScrolledPanel(self)
        # main sizer for everything:
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # create grids
        fixGrid = glib.Grid(fixedScrolledPanel)
        resizableGrid = glib.Grid(resizableScrolledPanel)
        # customize grids
        fixGrid.CreateGrid(3,10)
        resizableGrid.CreateGrid(20,10)
        fixGrid.SetDefaultCellBackgroundColour( [176, 196, 222] )#light steel blue
        fixGrid.SetGridLineColour([0,0,0])
        [fixGrid.SetRowLabelValue(idx, ["row 1","row 2","row 3"][idx]) for idx in range(3)]
        resizableGrid.SetColLabelSize(0)
        fixGrid.SetRowLabelSize( wx.grid.GRID_AUTOSIZE )
        resizableGrid.SetRowLabelSize( fixGrid.GetRowLabelSize() )
        # Create the grids sizers
        fixedSizer  = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        resizeSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        resizableScrolledPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=True, scroll_y=True)
        fixedScrolledPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scroll_y=False)

        fixedSizer.Add\
        (
        fixGrid,
        proportion = 1,
        flag       = wx.EXPAND,
        border     = 0
        )
        fixedScrolledPanel.SetSizer(fixedSizer)
        fixedSizer.SetSizeHints(fixedScrolledPanel)

        mainSizer.Add\
        (
        fixedScrolledPanel,
        proportion = 0,
        flag       = wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP,
        border     = 5
        )

        resizeSizer.Add\
        (
        resizableGrid,
        proportion = 1,
        flag       = wx.EXPAND,
        border     = 0
        )

        resizableScrolledPanel.SetSizer(resizeSizer)

        mainSizer.Add\
        (
        resizableScrolledPanel,
        proportion = 1,
        flag       = wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM,
        border     = 5
        )
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)

# The main frame:
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,title=title, size=(850,500))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(grids(self),1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame(None, "Scroll Test")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```